# How to increase my enemy's health every time player gets an increment of 50 score?

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

To increase difficulty of my game over time, I am thinking of increasing enemy's health everytime player's score gets an increment of 50. Each enemy kill gives 10 points to the player.

Now I don't understand why I am having trouble with this as it can't be that complicated.

This is how I am trying to make it work but creating a new instance of enemy resets the health back to original (100). How can I get around it so that new updated health gets applied to all new instances of enemies after every 50 score increment?

Code snippet:

```
struct Enemy
{
    Float2 mPos         = Float2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    Float2 mVelocity    = Float2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    Float2 Knockback    = Float2(0.0f, 0.0f);

    float mHealth       = 0.0f;
    float mLastHit      = 0.0f;
};

// How often enemies spawn
gameState->mEnemySpawnCounter = 5.0f;

Enemy* enemy = new Enemy();
gameState->mEnemies.push_back(enemy);

// This is likely the issue as after a new enemy spawns, health gets reset to 100. How can I get around it?
enemy->mHealth = 100.0f;

// Enemies health increases specifically on multiples of 50 score and then gets reset back to 100 (If the score becomes 60 for example)
if (gameState->mPlayerScore % 50 == 0 && gameState->mPlayerScore > 0)
{
    enemy->mHealth += 20.0f;
}
```

I guess I need another variable to keep track of enemy health? Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: When the player "levels up", do you want to change the health of all enemies, including already spawned enemies, or only the health of enemies that will be spawned in the future?

Comment: For the future maybe there should be some enemy base health variable that is incremented in some way when the level up occurs. Then when you spawn a new enemy it would use this base health.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Only the health of enemies that will be spawned in the future.

Comment: Out of topic, I don't understand why my question was closed. I took out most of my code I have already and only put the code here that would be the most useful to understand and solve my problem (shortest code necessary as it's said).

Comment: You just increase the helth of any enemy created when the player has a multiple of 50 hp at the time of enemy creation. what you're trying to do is probably `enemy->mHealth = 100f + static_cast<int>(gameState->mPlayerScore) / 50 * 20f;` (minus the cast, if `mPlayerScore` is integral) Btw: You'll probably want to use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Enemy>>` instead of a vector of raw pointers to allow vector to automatically take care of freeing the memory, or even simpler, if no stable enemy addresses are required `std::vector<Enemy>`

Comment: As an alternative to the formula in my previous comment, simply keep track of the total enemy health via a variable and make sure this variable never goes out of scope between executions of your logic...

Comment: @fabian So you're saying to make the 'enemy->mHealth' variable not go out of scope? To make it not go out of scope, can I store the variable on heap or maybe make it static?

Comment: `static` in general is not the preferred option: It's better to avoid a global state which would also make it simpler to restart the game, should you want to add this functionality in the future. A good design would probably store this in an `GameRun` or similarly named entity that has a lifetime from the start of a fresh game until the gameover. Assuming the rest of the code is written properly, introducing a `float totalEnemyHealth;` variable that has the same lifetime as the vector of enemies and initialize it to 100 at the start. would work though.

Comment: Btw: it's not `enemy->mHealth` that goes out of scope, since `Enemy` objects are heap-allocated anyways.

Comment: @fabian Fair enough. For now I've made it work using the first solution you mentioned. Will have a look at the alternative option later if need be. Thanks!

Comment: **I am voting to reopen the question because** in my opinion, it can not be expected of OP to reduce the problem to a simpler problem. Any such attempt would likely have resulted in OP asking about an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Although this question is probably of no use to anyone else, in my opinion, this does not warrant closing the question.